# How to get ethernet card speed as 1000Mb/s into Centos

Tags: centos6.5

I have setup a network which fully supported 1000Mb/s speed. Same network shows 1000Mb/s speed in Windows system but in Centos it is showing 100Mb/s speed. Why?

My ethtool output as follow

```
 [root@localhost ~]# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 2
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Is that a dual boot system or two different systems? If it's the second are they indeed connected to the same switch? Please include the output of `ethtool <NIC>`.

Comment: What is make /model of nic card ? Are you using in physical server ? Is this server are using dual boot between win/Centos It is possible to get out put from you are server following command. > ethtool ethX
> > lshw -class network

Comment: No it is not dual boot.

Comment: And could you update your question with the output of `ethtool`?

Comment: Yes I am using physical server.
My system is not dual boot both are different systems. 
Yes I am able to get output from this command :- ethtool eth0

Comment: To me this sounds more like a hardware problem than a software problem. Maybe the switchport, the cable, or the NIC itself is faulty and not capable of operating at full speed.

Comment: In windows it show 1000Mbps in linux it show 100mbps, 
Both have same cable and cisco gigabit unmanaged switch.

Comment: Did you move the cable between the computers when testing?

Comment: Yes I have move the cable between the computers when testing.

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the duplex in the CentOS system? http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-add-ethtool-duplex-settings-permanent.html

Comment: Does manually forcing gigabit speeds work i.e. `ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on` ?  Auto-negotionation is required for gigabit but on some switches the negotiation doesn't always agree that Gigabit is supported by both sides :(

Comment: Yes I have done manually forcing gigabit speed using this:- ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on  . But after doing this speed shows unknown and network goes down.